# Switching between windows of one application in multiple spaces

Tags: keyboard, window-manager, spaces, mission-control

I know you can use `` command + ` `` to switch between windows in one program in one space.

But this is only in the one space, if you have other windows from the same App in different spaces ... it won't switch to that space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a shortcut to do this, though it doesn't cycle between windows; it only allows you to choose one. But it will switch to it regardless of which space it's on. It's a convenient way to access App Exposé for any app.

Press <kbd>Cmd+Tab</kbd> to open the application switcher. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd>) to select the app you want, then keep holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd>. Then press <kbd>1</kbd> to see all of the selected app's windows. You can then select a window by typing its title, or with the arrow keys.

Re-tested and verified on macOS 11 Big Sur in 2022. This process includes open and minimized windows, but not full-screen windows. It also doesn't work when initialized from a full-screen window, which seems strange.

Comment: I don't understand this suggestion at all, since ```Cmd+Tab``` is modal - you can't lift the ```Cmd``` key without exiting the whole thing. Does this suggest to press ```1``` while ```Cmd``` is still down? Or did the whole switching dialog work very differently 9 years ago when this was written?

Comment: Great question, thank you. Yes, the suggestion involves continuing to hold down `Cmd`, but as written, that's not clear at all. I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: This is a fascinating answer, I use `Cmd+Tab` all day, but who would have thought to press `1` while in that menu.

Comment: Q and H work as well, to Quit or Hide the selected app. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a direct shortcut for that.

An alternative would be using the application windows exposé, which shows all of a particular application's windows (across all spaces). I think the default keyboard shortcut for this is F10, but you can change it in System Preferences > Mission Control.

(You can also set up a gesture for it if you're using a trackpad.)

Comment: I didn't think there was a shortcut but thought it would be worth an ask.

Answer (score 3):

There is no keyboard shortcut that will switch spaces for you.

But there is a shortcut to do what you want:

<kbd>Ctrl ^</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

Also you can swipe down with three fingers on a touchpad/trackpad to open App Exposé

Comment: I mean, yes, that does display all open windows from x app, but I was hoping for something that would flip between them like `command+\``. PS, for others: It's triggering the Mission Control, "Application windows" shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard, for anyone who may have this disabled (like I did).

Comment: If you need only use keyboard you can just use arrow keys for navigation and Enter key to activate selected window after entering Application windows mode using shortcut above

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no system default to cycle windows - some apps have this built in, such as Terminal being able to command-N between different open windows (in the order to they were opened), yet Safari with no such behavior.

Apple seems to think that we'd all prefer the eye candy of Expose/Mission Control/etc rather than a standard shortcut system.

Comment: Eye candy is great... but only is it works fast every time... Mission Control isn't always as responsive as I would like and I hardly use it... I much prefer "Spaces" as it was in Snow Leopard.

Comment: Agreed totally, I haven't seen anything compelling in Lion to even upgrade my offices.  What I probably miss most is the ability to resize windows from all edges...

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue - I want to switch between windows of the same application (housed in different spaces) using something simple like a keyboard shortcut, rather than messing with the trackpad.

What is interesting is that Microsoft Excel for mac actually does this! You just use the normal shortcut  and it'll switch between open windows of excel, regardless of what space their in.

Doesn't work with any other programs (including Word, etc) that I have noticed so far though.