# How to switch between different Chrome windows with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, application-switcher

Switching between applications is easy with <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Switching between tabs is easy with <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>}</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Switching between separate windows within an application is easy with <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>.

However, that last one doesn't seem to work with Google Chrome (Version 27.0.1453.110) on OS X 10.8.4. Is there a leopard shortcut specific for Chrome to switch between different windows?

Comment: also for reference is http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Tab also allows you to switch directions between tabs.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> works for me with the same versions of Chrome and OS X, so it might be something specific to your installation.

You could try temporarily resetting Chrome's preferences or disabling extensions. Or change the shortcut from System Preferences or test if it works on a different account.

Comment: You're right... it does work. The problem is with OSX spaces. If I have two chrome windows open in the same space, CMD + ` switches between those windows. However, if I move chrome, or any other application, to two or more spaces, CMD + ` does not switch between those windows. I'm going to mark this as the answer since it does answer my question. I'll create a new question regarding switching between windows in different spaces.

Comment: You guys save life time for me!!! it's awesome

Comment: @KrisAnderson, did you manage to ask that question somewhere? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @KrisAnderson, would you mind sharing the new question you mentionned regarding switching between windows in different spaces.

Comment: @KrisAnderson is it this question - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50445/switching-between-windows-of-one-application-in-multiple-spaces. Unfortunately it doesn’t have an answer

Comment: I am using a guest computer right now, I just logged in just to upvote this, damn, why cant mac keep 1 shortcut to switch between apps and windows just like the windows. You start to appreciate windows when you leave it!

Answer (score 59):

This issue is so **annoying** for me, and today I finally got it resolved! So, in hope to help some poor soul like myself, I want to share what I did:

[image: Screenshot]

- Go to System Preference --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts tab --> **`Move focus to next window`**
- Set it to <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

---

Updated screenshots for MacOS Ventura 13.3.1:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Using a non english layout, it made it easy to figure out what it was

Comment: In my case, this was already checked, but pressing this keystroke simply does nothing. I disabled and re-enabled the option, and edited the key to set it to the same thing (still <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>), then it suddenly starts working.

Comment: Saved my life - got kb with German layout (vielen dank) - key above Tab contains §/± chars. The backtick is between left shift and Y but `cmd` + ` didn't switch the window by default.

Comment: This only works if the window isn't maximized.

Answer (score 14):

To show Chrome windows (this applies to other apps as well) press: <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd> (arrow down).

Active windows of the current application would be shown larger (if you've multiple monitors, they will show on other screen as well), including minimized at the bottom.

From there, use arrow keys to switch between different windows and confirm your selection with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> (to switch between all apps press <kbd>Tab</kbd>). It should work for multiple displays as well. Hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> to cancel the selection.

<sub>Above tested on El Capitan (10.11).</sub>

Comment: Doesn't show all windows if they're spread across different workspaces, which is what the gist of the problem is.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It works for me with multiple monitors though.

Comment: Right, but do you have multiple [spaces](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21872?locale=en_US)?

Comment: Maybe if you hit your arrows towards another workspace, it'll switch to another? Or use the shortcuts, like Control-1 or 2, or Alt+Arrows?

Comment: This is the best answer for me, I need to be able to quickly identify and switch to Gmail vs. Hangouts vs. Calendar.

Answer (score 7):

For those using Snow Leopard 10.6.8, these options can be set under the OSX "System Preferences" > Keyboard > "Keyboard Shortcuts" Tab > "Keyboard and Text Input".

Apparently, by default Cmd+` is set to "Move focus to next window in appl...". However, this shortcut doesn't work for me because my keyboard is Japanese, and therefore I need to press Shift to access the `. It turns out that OSX always receives a Shift+Cmd+@. So, what I did was to replace that shortcut with Cmd+@ and now it works.

Hope that helps people having similar issues.

PS: You can use the "Move focus to active or next window", which defaults to Ctrl+F4, Shift+Ctrl+F4 for the previous window.

Answer (score 5):

@Hugo Chrome allows to set up more users to get more "environments" inside your chrome (bookmarks, opened tabs, session and so forth). it's very useful to split your business and private browsing.

So, <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> is very useful. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not provide an answer to the question—leave a comment once you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked in any way...  Would have been a down-vote if I had the reputation on this SE site for it.

Comment: @Jehu, Hmm, there seems to be no way to switch between these "environments" when they have more than one windows.

Comment: At least for me on a `SE` keyboard layout the Command + ` shortcut for witching between windows in chrome profiles does not work - so this would be the ONLY way to switch between chrome profiles via the keybaord

Answer (score 4):

My case was slightly different - one chrome window was normal ( not maximized ) and another chrome windows was maximized. The above solution `cmd + '` didn't work in my case.

When one chrome window is maximized it gets its own space, found that i can use `control key + left or right arrow keys` to switch back between these 2 chrome windows.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut doesn't work for me (Chrome 38.0 on Mac OS X 10.9.50).

But <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> seems to work instead (and works for other apps too).

Though, again, it doesn't work if the windows are spread across desktops/spaces.

Comment: CMD+F1 does nothing. Tested in Google Chrome 48 in El Capitan.

Answer (score 2):

Control + F4 will switch back & forth between open chrome browsers but only after configuring the Function keys to only work with Fn key in System Preferences > keyboard options.

Comment: This cycles between all windows. So it would work if you only had two chrome windows open.

Answer (score 2):

So I found what was , for me , the real problem.
I went into System Preferences" > Keyboard > "Keyboard Shortcuts" Tab > "Keyboard and Text Input and I found this:

[image: Sorry for Italian lang.]

Sorry for Italian lang.

Start from bottom, third row.
Have attention for ***cmd + '*** at first it was ***cmd + `***

So I simply changed it and now It works perfectly.

Hope this can help.

Comment: It helped me to active the last radio button option (All Controls). Because I am not always in a Text Field.

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle between windows in the same Space/desktop, and also across all of them.

To toggle between windows of the same application in the **same space** use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>`</kbd>  ("Move focus to the next window").

However, what shows **windows in all spaces** from the same app is the "Application Windows" shortcut:  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  +  <kbd>↓</kbd>  which shows all of them:

[image]

Now you can either use keyboard arrows or click the one you want to transition to.

### Pro tip

What's very helpful to me is using configuring a hot corner so I don't even need to press keys.

(Preferences -> Desktop & Screensaver -> Hot Corners):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To switch between users in Chrome, use <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> and then use your arrow keys to select the user you want and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This isn't as fast as a key combination normally is but it is quicker than using the mouse. To see where this key combination comes from see [Chrome's support forum](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165450?hl=en).

Comment: Chrome users? What is that? The command doesnt do anything for me

Comment: "Chrome users" are currently seen in the "People" menu in Chrome on MacOS and also via clicking your user icon in the upper right hand corner. You can have multiple google accounts associated with Chrome (very handy). The keyboard shortcut in this answer allows to switch between people, even when minimized, which is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There will be ShortCuts “Alt+PageUp” & “Alt+PageDown” available in the next version of our extension [TabIt - NewTab](https://alexperience.me/projects/tabit/tabit-newtab) (precisely in v15.01). They will allow to switch between neighbouring Chrome windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please note that we have [some rules](/help/promotion) you have to follow when linking to your own website.

Comment: On a second thought, these ShortCuts aren't appropriate for such an extension. But I have moved them to another one, called ChRAM:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chram/pogibncdlnomiioielcgkhhgcmhokcma

Answer (score 1):

In order for any suggested keyboard shortcuts to work, none of the windows can be in Full Screen.  To exit Full Screen, choose `View > Exit Full Screen`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Chrome Windows maximized (ie. each Chrome window is in its own [Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_(software))), the keyboard shortcut to toggle between Spaces will do the job for you. By default keyboard shortcut to toggle between Spaces is control + right arrow key or control + left arrow key. If this doesn't work, check for keyboard shortcuts on your mac under System Preferences > Keyboard > Mission Control and attributes 'Move left a space' and 'Move right a space'.

Answer (score 1):

[MAC users] When you have several google sessions open or other applications as vscode with different projects per window, you can switch between them using COMMAND + TAB after that UP or DOWN to choose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when I went in to system preferences and keyboard shortcuts the shortcut was set to cmd+. When I marked it and gave it the same shortcut, It suddenly works just fine:)

Answer (score 0):

I just do control+left/right arrow. Not sure if this only works because I have the swipe between apps enabled with my apple mouse...
**UPDATE**
I found that the problem was apparently in chrome itself(for me) and that to make it work you need the chrome windows to be minimized for it to work. The problem might be in the shortcut itself, but "cmd+`" does work with other applications. So, the solution I'm currently using is just to minimize and then manually increasing the window size to fit the full screen.
Found this answer from https://superuser.com/a/1177594. If this isn't the problem, try the other solutions.

Comment: That's the space switching shortcut, you need to place your windows in different adjacent spaces.

Comment: I changed it...

Answer (score 0):

Review the mission control shortcuts for switching between OSX spaces.  The following link answers your question because you are using Chrome browser AND OSX spaces.  Also some sources frequently refer to spaces as desktops.

[macOS: Navigating between desktops using keyboard shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362614/macos-navigating-between-desktops-using-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: The link you have provided opens up a question with three answers. Which of them are you referring to? Note that you can provide a direct link to an answer using the share button at the bottom of an answer. In addition, it is  better practice to describe in your answer how the linked material answers the question explicitly with enough detail so that someone reading your answer later on can figure it out even if the linked material is deleted for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Happy news for German/Austrian/Swiss keyboard users:

You cannot toggle with

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

You need to do

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Also, this has been available for the keyboard layouts you state for some time already. I think users could just refer to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/93889/489896). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342335)

Answer (score -2):

cmd + `works only if the windows are not in fullscreen mode. If they are in fullscreen mode, cmd +` doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

I'm using Mavericks and <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> does not work for me. However, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> does.

Comment: CMD+. does nothing. Tested in Google Chrome 48 in El Capitan.