# Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

I opened two Google Chrome windows (because I am using multiple Gmails) and when I do the <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd> shortcut it just shows me other applications that I opened but does not show me the other Chrome windows that are already opened.

How to switch to the other Google Chrome window that I opened using keyboard shortcut?

Comment: What is the hotkey for Windows Keyboard connected to mac?

Comment: Should be an option to make it the same as on linux and windows, show all windows so you only need to use cmd+tab and not add arrows into it.

Answer (score 723, accepted):

**UK Keyboard**
*[see below for other languages]*

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>    <kbd>`</kbd>  to go the other way.

Left of z on a UK keyboard [non-shifted ~ ]

[image]

**Note: This only works if all windows are in the same Space, not if they are spread over multiple Spaces, or if any are fullscreen.**
To overcome this for non-fullscreen window, use <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> as usual and on the icon of the application you want to switch windows in press the down arrow key (with <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> still pressed). Then use left/right keys to navigate to the desired window across spaces and desktops. *To emphasise, This fails for any fullscreened windows, whilst continuing to work for any that are not.*

You can also achieve this by right-clicking the app's icon in the Dock - this is the only method that will also switch to fullscreen windows, the other methods will not.

*From comments* - You can check which key command it is for your language by switching to Finder, then look at the Window menu for 'Cycle through windows'...

[image]

BTW, specifically in Chrome, Safari & Firefox, but no other app I know of on Mac,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>(number)</kbd>  will select individual tabs on the frontmost window.

*It also would appear that  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>   is yet another of those language-specific shortcuts; so if anyone finds any more variants, please specify for which language & keyboard type.*

*If anybody finds new combos for different languages, please check Keyboard layout here - This is a mirror of the very useful old Apple KB page, now gone from Apple [How to identify keyboard localizations](https://www.topteksystem.com/blog/apple-tutorials/identifying-keyboard-localization/) - & add that as well as which Input Source you use in System Prefs > Keyboard > Input Sources.

Add a keyboard picture from the KB page too, if that would help.

That will make it easier for future Googlers.*

Further info:
You can change the keys in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard...
though it doesn't list the reverse direction, it does still work when you add shift to that new combo. I tested by moving mine from  <kbd>`</kbd>   (and  <kbd>~</kbd> ) to  <kbd>§</kbd>  (and  <kbd>±</kbd> )

[image]

You can use the alternative of  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F4</kbd>  [visible in the prefs window above] but that almost indiscriminately marches through every single open window on all Spaces, without switching to the correct Space each time. It's really not too useful unless you use a single Space, just included here for completeness.

Comment: Upvote for "press the down arrow key (with Cmd ⌘ still pressed). Then use left/right keys to navigate to the desired window across spaces and desktops." !!

Comment: **NOTE:** ⌘ ` doesn't work for windows running in full screen

Comment: @VVK -This information is right at the top of the answer. All rules change for fullscreen. One of the very many reasons I never use it.

Comment: Cmd-1 ... Cmd-9 works in Firefox also

Comment: A workaround to cycle through FULLSCREEN windows of an app (let say Chrome): 
1. fn + control + F3 => move focus to dock
2. -> or <- to focus on desired app
3. arrow up to open menu of that app
4. select the desired window

Comment: The down-arrow functionality you're talking about is called App Exposé. It's great. You can go to it directly using control +  ↓ , just like Mission Control's  control   +  ↑ . Once in App Exposé, you can tab through different applications using  tab  or three-finger swipe left/right. I have three-finger swipe-down mapped to app exposé and three-finger swipe-up mapped to mission control so my three-finger swipe gestures completely mimic the  control -arrow options.

Comment: I need to switch between windows of the same app that live in different workspaces (aka are full screen) with a keyboard shortcut. I'm trying the Cmd ⌘ + Tab, then Down key, but have had no success so far. Using macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Anyone else experiencing this? Is there an alternative?

Comment: I am using Big Sur Beta 2 and this is not working on it. It used to work for me for the earlier release.

Comment: On a French (Canada) Keyboard, it's cmd + "ù" or cmd + shift + "ù". Works great! Thanks!

Comment: @M.Beausoleil - please add new languages as a separate answer, including picture if you can find one on https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201794 There is already an answer for French Canadian & it doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: I added an answer. The option+cmd+à doesn't work for me, but it might be the input language that is different. I tested a bunch and wasn't able to replicate the previous answer. I tested my answer on 2 keyboards and they worked fine.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if connecting a PC-keyboard to the mac, it seems it's still the button just right of shift (at least on a Logitech K120) and not the actual ` on the other end of the keyboard...

Comment: @VVK then how we can do it by a short key, doc method is very slow :/

Comment: I miss windows here :/

Comment: omg for some very simple things apple does have 0 sense. i have been spending hours and hours for such a simple feature that is enabled by default in windows. if it wasnt for batter efficiency it is enough for me to throw away this mac.

Comment: @damdafayton - it's enabled by default in Mac too, & exactly like in Windows, if you don't know where it is already, it's hard to find.

Comment: you cant switch between tabs of same app in Mac. some people advise to use cmd+` which doesnt work on Turkish Mac. Even if it works it doesnt work when the app is fullscreen. this is absolute total nonsense.

Comment: For a Turkish layout, see the answer below. As mentioned at the very top of this answer, this is one of the commands that changes by language/layout. Switching tabs is a different thing entirely & uses Cmd/[number] Fullscreen is a disaster, I won't defend that - nor would I ever use it.

Answer (score 154):

### On US keyboard:

Next window: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>

Previous window:   <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>

<kbd>`</kbd>  is the key on top of <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, so it's similar to <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut.

[image]

### On other language:

Go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> on the left menu, select `Keyboard` -> on the right menu, select `Move focus to next window`. You can now change the shortcut to which ever key is on top of <kbd>Tab</kbd> in your keyboard to work like intended.

Attention:
Doesn't work when window is in full-screen. In that case, you have to use Mission Control shortcuts, e.g.   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  <kbd>→</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  <kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: lifesaver answer

Comment: BTW, how to toggle between full-screen windows

Answer (score 71):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> of course will work but I do it in different way.

I do the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> when I do that, I don't release the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> so the opened apps are still visible. While it is visible, I will press <kbd>▼</kbd>.

This way it will show all your opened applications with animated displays so you can navigate using arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks for the down arrow tip. The problem is that when you press Cmd+tab, it goes to the next app, so you have to Cmd+Shift+Tab then down

Comment: You can accomplish the same just using control + ↓ instead of all the complicated sequencing/keeping Cmd help down etc.

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze THIS! Thanks for helping me manage my many IntelliJ project windows!!

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze it will loose selection focus, so you will have to use mouse (which defeats the whole purpose)

Comment: @saurabhgupta No. You navigate with the arrow keys, as in ji-ruh's comment. If you do not know how to do this, why are you responding to my comment instead of to ji-ruh? As far as using the mouse or using the arrow keys, there is no difference in behavior between control + ↓ and Cmd+tab.

Comment: By the way, Cmd + tab and then ↓ while holding Cmd pressed doesn't work any longer in newer versions of macOS, it now does something else. To get the navigation ji-ruh was describing, press control + ↓, and then navigate between the open applications using the arrow keys as I described (or the mouse if you really want to @saurabhgupta).

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze - i dont know. im not mac user anymore.

Comment: @ji-ruh I didn't ask anything.

Comment: @ji-ruh: Thanks so much for this! It always bothered me that cmd-tab brings up *all* the app windows when I just need one.  You just saved me a lot of mousing time.  Cheers!

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze: Pressing Cmd+\` and then ↓ still works for me in Mac OS Ventura (13.0) to show all open windows in the chosen app. Pressing Ctrl+↓ does show all open windows in the current app only; the solution in the answer does let you do the same for any app without having to separately switch to it first.

Answer (score 27):

**Swiss, German & Swedish** keyboard:

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd><</kbd>
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>></kbd>

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me, trying to switch between windows of VS Code.

Comment: doesnt work on German Keyboard. Working Cmd+Shit+`

Answer (score 22):

I figured out why <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> doesn't work half the time. Your applications can not be in full screen mode, which is kinda silly but I tried it on the Finder window like mentioned above, no problem. Took both chrome windows out of full screen and the shortcut works like a charm.

**UPDATE**

The best I could come up with is pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd> on your keypad. It cycles through all your full screen windows, but hey at least it's something.

Also North American keyboard settings, though I don't think that actually matters since the issue, assuming at least, is the app was fullscreen.

Comment: ctrl+left/right seems to be the best choice when all of your windows are in full screen. Which mine are all the time. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

On Slovenian keyboard it's <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> which is impossible to click and won't activate on a Slovenian keyboard. The only solution I found it to change the shortcut to <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd><</kbd>. How to change the shortcut: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280221/214825

<sup>Slovenian layout</sup> 
[image]

Comment: Same in Scandinavian keyboard layouts. Seems like a bug to me, using dead keys as shortcuts just does not work and should not be the default for those layouts.

Comment: Is this still true?  I use a "generic USB" keyboard set to US International, and I think ` is classified as a "dead key."  I can do this with it: àòèìù. I can also switch between windows in the same app using cmd+` and I just verified the same in Safari by using cmd+n followed by cmd+`.  That doesn't automatically mean that Slovenian and Scandinavian keyboard layout users can do the same, but it may imply that the bug isn't be as simple as "using dead keys as shortcuts just does not work" as suggested in the comment above mine.

Comment: The problem is with Visual Studio Code for me. When I try Cmd + Shift + ^, it basically tries typing in the ^ character rather than actually executing the shortcut. This problem did not come up in Microsoft Word however.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is the way to go on OS X to change between windows of the same application.

Comment: You need to add what nationality keyboard & OS that works on. This is yet another of those 'changes by language' settings

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>±</kbd> (the one above <kbd>tab</kbd>) does the job.
OSX Yosemite 10.
en-US language layout

Answer (score 5):

The key combination to switch between app documents in the Spanish keyboard is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>^`[</kbd> (the key next to the letter P, which is the actual backtick key in the Spanish keyboard and also prints the "^" and "[" symbols when used in conjunction with Shift and Alt respectively).

[image: Spanish Apple keyboard]

Answer (score 4):

On a French Canadian Keyboard layout, it's <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>à</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

For Turkish Q Keyboard (Turkey) press at the same <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

To toggle between windows of the same application in the **same desktop/space** use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>`</kbd> . You can change the shortcut here:

[image]
I usually have my Chrome windows **spread across different desktops** so it doesn't work for me. Thankfully, we have  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  +  <kbd>↓</kbd>  which shows **all** of them:

[image]

Now you can use keyboard arrows or click the one you want to transition to.

### Pro tip: hot corners ‍

How about simply moving the mouse to a screen corner to show them all instead?

[image]

Comment: Hot Corners is nice! System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Hot Corners Button.

Answer (score 2):

**Canadian French - CSA language with French (Canadian) Keyboard**

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>ù</kbd>

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  +  <kbd>ù</kbd>  to go the other way.

[image]

**Canadian French - CSA language with US English Keyboard**

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>`</kbd>

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  +  <kbd>`</kbd>  to go the other way.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + number works for me, just make sure that your caps lock is not "on". I am using macOS Sierra 10.12

Comment: Cmd [number] is for selecting individual tabs in a single window.

Answer (score -1):

cmd+` shortcut won't work if the windows are fullscreen.

use `control + ->` and `control + <-` to switch windows:

[image]