# How to change the default shortcut for "move focus to next window" to something else?

Tags: macos, shortcut

On Slovenian keyboard it's impossible to click the default shortcut.

Comment: If you have time, it might be useful to add the Slovenian default to this question, as we're trying to add info for as many international versions as possible - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app

Comment: @Tetsujin will add an answer there as well.

Comment: Thank you for that - the keys are so difficult to figure out if you don't use that language or layout. I did post a comment under your answer there, because I'd love to be able to add one more working default to our growing list.  Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 13):

Go to "System Preferences" -> "Keyboard" -> "Shortcuts" -> "Keyboard" -> hold the option key and left mouse click on the current shortcut on the right side from "Move focus to next window" -> then enter your new keyboard shortcut.

[image]

<sup>picture of UK defaults showing different backtick</sup>
[image]

Comment: Apologies for tagging you in so many replies. Again, I've edited another picture into your answer just to give some comparison [rather than post another answer as a discussion which is not good for the SE format.] We can always tidy up these comments afterwards. The key command for window drawer doesn't seem to be a 'backtick' `\`` but some kind of 'vertical apostrophe'. I've posted the UK defaults as a picture, showing the backtick as a distinction.