# shortcut for cycling between different windows of Finder on Mac (not the tab)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have macOSSierra 10.12.5, I have checked the keyboard shortcuts in system preferences and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>   (command + backtick) is enabled indeed!
Yet, when I open two finder windows (not the tabs), I cannot cycle between them. I explicitly have to right click on the finder icon in the doc and select one of the open folders. This is bad, really bad for productivity, since I have to switch every time between mouse and keyboard.

Is there a way out of this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are they in the same Space? It only works if they are. Also, what Language is the keyboard & your input language? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938 for language variations.

Comment: @Tetsujin, the keyboard is of type en-US. I am quite not sure what space means here, can you please elaborate?  I Just open the finder in the current window from two different locations in terminal by typing : " open . "

Comment: Explanation of Spaces - https://support.apple.com/HT204100

Comment: Also, double-check that the Finder Window menu shows the correct key command

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking on System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts that the shortcut is indeed active and enabled, check also on the "Window" menu on a Finder window. There should be the shortcut. In this case <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>".

[image: Screenshot]

As you've been suggested as well, check that your PHYSICAL keyboard has this key and doesn't require a modifier (like SHIFT) to be used. If you're using a foreign keyboard set, like a spanish or azerty keyboard, for example, you need to find out what the right key is.

Another idea would be to go to System Preferences / Keyboard / Input Sources and enable "Show input in menubar". You'll get a new menubar icon, from which you can select "Show Keyboard Viewer". In this tiny keyboard you can see where your keys are mapped. Maybe (just maybe) your tick (<kbd>`</kbd>) key is not where you think it is. This viewer should help you.

[image: Screenshot]