# How to change the switch window key?

Tags: keyboard, window-manager, internationalization

On my Macbook with a US-International physical keyboard, the windows of one application are cycled with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. Now I also use an iMac that has a German keyboard (the printing on the keys).  I switched the layout to US-International, but weirdly, the windows of one application are now switched with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> instead. This is exactly the key that would be in the same location as <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> would I be using the German keyboard layout. I am not using that layout, though and I don't want to cycle windows with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>.

How can I customize this setting?

Comment: Just to clarify - the position of the key moves, depending on Language? or... you're conflicted because you want the key to be above Tab [US keyboard types] rather than left of Z [almost all other keyboard types]? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app

Comment: No matter the keyboard layout that is selected (in software), on this Mac <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> switches the windows. If I (in software) select the german layout, then this is next to the left shift, if I select the US layout it is in the bottom right.

Comment: To answer the question. I want it to be left of Z and use a US-International layout. For this the window switch needs to be evoked by "CMD+`". Currently it is evoked by CMD+>

Comment: OK, then you're probably stuck - though you can pick a key, it's going to move with your language selection. There's a method to change the key in the last part of my answer on the linked QA

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't get it. It appears as if all settings (system language, location, keyboard layout) are the same as on my other computer where CMD-` is the key. Yet on this computer CMD-> is the key. I don't see an option to customize this in the list on System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard...

Comment: @Tetsujin OK, thanks. Problem solved with your help. I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: I added a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language specific shortcuts are set up when the computer is first set up. In my case, the computer was set up in German and I only later switched it to English. Then the default hotkeys do not change. The desired behaviour (switching windows with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> could be enabled by going to System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard and then pressing "Restore defaults". In particular "Move focus to next window" changes then.