# How to set a key to mimic clicking an app in the dock

Tags: keybindings

I have multiple desktops on High Sierra. Given an app window (like Safari) on each desktop, I can click on the app icon on the dock, and it will cycle through the desktops with this app.

⌘-` will cycle app windows on this desktop

Can I set a key to cycle app-desktops?

Comment: Does `Ctrl - Right/Left Arrow` not work?

Comment: There's a difference between cycling desktops & cycling different windows of the same app if they're spread to other Spaces. Clicking the Dock icon will cycle all windows of an app in any Space, inc fullscreen. ⌘` will only cycle them in a single Space.

Comment: Actually, Cmd/Tab then down arrow will do the same thing... which kind of makes this a dupe of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938 even though I posted a different solution [my excuse, 1st coffee of the day;)

Comment: ok... sorry... after testing, no. Cmd/tab/arrows won't cycle to fullscreen Spaces, only clicking the Dock will do that...

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of task [QuicKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/) used to be very good at.

Press a button, return cursor to its start point.

It's still available [will run in nag-free demo mode for a month, then go to nagware unless you buy it] & has instructions to [install under more recent macOSes](http://startly.com/support/), but idk whether it's still up to the task.