# What's the shortcut to switch between app documents in a Spanish keyboard?

Tags: applications, shortcut

I know the shortcut to switch between app documents (or Finder windows) is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>, but in the Spanish keyboard to get a tilde you can't use a single key, you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ñ</kbd>.

I've tried pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ñ</kbd> but it doesn't work.

So how do I execute this shortcut with a Spanish keyboard layout?

Comment: A picture of your keyboard may help - Are you sure it's not just Cmd > or < ? That would fit with the pattern on most EU layouts. When we figure this out, we ought to add it to the list at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app BTW, in English it's not tilde ~, but backtick ` [which is un-shifted tilde] as you'll see from the linked QA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tetsujin. I've found the right key thanks to your suggestion, so I've added this info as an answer.

Comment: I've also added another answer in the question you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found out (thanks to a comment by @Tetsujin) that the key I'm looking for is not tilde (~) but backtick (`). In the Spanish keyboard that's the key next to the letter P, which looks like this: <kbd>^`[</kbd>

So the key combination to switch between app documents in the Spanish keyboard is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>^`[</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can find a complete list of keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences, under Keyboard, then Shortcuts. If one isn't listed you can also bind it to whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to remap the Cmd+` combination to just Ctrl+Tab, to match the behaviour in browsers such as Chrome, but then that key combination doesn't do anything in other applications. For example in Word it doesn't work. Pressing Ctrl+Tab just writes a Tab in the document instead of switching between Word documents. If I reset the key combination back to Cmd+` it does work as usual.