# Using Command + ` to cycle through windows across different Spaces in macOS Mojave

Tags: keyboard, mojave, spaces

I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>  often when switching between apps/windows.

I also have multiple Spaces that I typically use. I've found that using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> only cycles through windows in the current Space. Is there a way to have it cycle through all windows in an application, not just the one in the current space?

I found that <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>(n)</kbd> (where `(n)` is an integer) switches to a specific window of an application and handles windows across spaces fine, but I don't really want to have to remember which window is which number when switching around.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) If you can consider using Mouse/Trackpad, I find Application Windows Hot Corner super useful. It show all the app windows open across all the Spaces along with minimized windows.

Comment: CMD+ Option+(n) opens first bookmark of Safari. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii I think it might actually be application specific. That's how it works in Terminal (you can see the designation for each window in the list under Window), but I don't see those same designations when I'm in Chrome. So my "solution" isn't even universal.

Comment: Pitty there is no such option. In keyboard maestro, it seems that it doesn't work too

Comment: Spaces was never meant to be used that way. It's designed for 'one app, one space' not spread over multiple Spaces. Yes, it's a limitation, but as Spaces development was pretty much abandoned with the advent of the truly [imnso] useless fullscreen, I don't see it will ever be improved. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938 which has some [inconvenient] workarounds.