# Chrome apps are not treaded as standalone applications, what leads to app-switching problems

Tags: macos, mojave, google-chrome, application-switcher

I am using OSX and Chrome-Apps for many years now, but there is one issue that still annoys me and that happens on OSX only and is no issue on Linux or Windows.
The problem is that Chrome-Apps are not treaded like standalone apps, while they should.

This leads to several problems:

E.g. when I use a Chrome window and for example Google Keep simultaneously and switch back and forth between both windows using cmd-Tab I can switch to Keep but I cannot switch back.
Another example happens when using an app like Hyperdock. The Keep window is not displayed when hovering on the Keep icon, but it is displayed when hovering on the Chrome icon.

Is there a fix for this? Solutions like Fluid are not a good fix, because they do not provide the offline functionality that Chrome Apps provide.

Comment: As far as the Mac is concerned, they are merely different windows of the same process. I know of no way round this but see if this would help - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app

Comment: Yes of course you can use this to switch between the windows. Still it seems kind of ugly that you have a distinct icon but it is not a disctinct app.

Comment: tbh, it does sound very much like Google - they have a penchant for ignoring the standard Mac Toolbox for handling apps & their internal elements. It sounds like they're actually using some kind of launch wrapper to run an 'app' inside Chrome itself.

Comment: Yeah probably you are right. Maybe I should report on the chromium Google group

Comment: Maybe so - tbh, I don't know how Chrome deals with things like that - their flagrant disregard for the Mac toolbox means I generally avoid their offerings entirely.

Comment: Let's just try. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/PCgSxgQZWgk But yeah, my hopes are not to great on this one. Maybe I will avoid chrome apps once again, now I switched back to mac.