# Cannot toggle between YouTube on full screen and other apps in Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, shortcut, fullscreen, youtube

I recently switched by browser from Firefox to Google Chrome and now when I have a YouTube video on full screen it won't let me toggle between the video and other apps using the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> shortcut any more.

My OS is Mojave.

Has anyone else had this problem and know of a solution?

Comment: Not to be flippant, but *you went to Chrome!*  Not a fan of it; Firefox is much more stable, much less resource hungry and much more user friendly.  Chrome may have disabled that shortcut (or function) so you might want to try mapping it to something else.

Comment: Haha yes @Allan I did like Firefox. Mine just got a bug that kept freezing my computer. I should have just re-installed it.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm running Firefox on 4 platforms (macOS, iOS, FreeBSD, and Windows) and haven't run across any freezing.  I did have an issue with the [device syncing features](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1280289) and not long after I posted, it was seemingly solved.  I'd definitely try posting there as well as here because they're pretty responsive.

Comment: This isn't designed to work on fullscreen apps or across different Spaces - already covered on https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193938/85275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. When you go full screen, it becomes kind of a new desktop (three finger swipe up, at the top you see all the desktops). The only way to switch between full screen items is via switching desktops.

You can swipe to the other desktops by swiping three finger either right or left or use <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can do what I wanted to do easily in Firefox. So I have switched back.