# Command + Tab in the same application with many windows

Tags: macos, catalina

What I want to do is: if I have 3 open pdf's files, 3 open word's files, among other applications, **I want to press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the 3 pdf's AND the 3 word's will appear**.

For example, in the image below, there are 3 Word files open, and 2 Safari windows. But when I press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> **the Word application appears only ONCE and the SAFARI application appears only ONCE too**:

[image: 3 Word's and 2 Safari's]

[image: Command Tab Example]

But for example, **in Windows 10 that three word's files appears in <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>**. I didn't find a windows image with 3 Word files. But I found one with two Google Chrome windows open. It's the same example:

[image: Windows Example]

I don't know if there will be a setting for that or I will just have to press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>+ <kbd>↑</kbd> and select one.

Comment: I honestly cannot tell the difference between what you're asking for & what the Windows example appears to be. Your goal is really not clear. Cmd/Tab will bring forward one application. That app may have several windows, one will come to the front, usually the last one you used. Your example images, btw, are not from Cmd/Tab but from Mission Control/Exposé

Comment: @Tetsujin I gave an example of mission control so you can see how many Word's files I have. 
What I want is when I press Cmd/tab I want that the applicatioin Word  appear 3 times. And the Safari application 2 times. Like in Windows 10. And NOT only one, like in Mac (like in the second picture)

Comment: You are trying to fight a paradigm difference. Each Windows 'window' is a different process. macOS apps have multiple windows of a single process. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938

Comment: Oh, okay. I didn't know that. Thank you so much for the help anyway!