# How to cycle windows of the same app on Czech keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

cmd+tilde does not work as the key below Esc is mapped to '<' character on my layout. I cannot find any preferences to remap this. Franky I am surprised this does not work, this mapping should be bound to a key and not a character.

Is this a bug that should be opened at Apple?

Thanks

Comment: See if any of these can help. If you do find it, we can add that information to keep it all in one place. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275

Comment: Which one worked? We can add the info for future users.