# `cmd+tab` to last opened Preview window

Tags: preview, mission-control

Consider this situation: I have two Preview windows with file1.pdf and file2.pdf, and another app, say Chrome, on a MacBook Pro with macOS Catalina.

[image: Open apps]

I navigate between the two pdf files with the three fingers scroll on the trackpad, and between the Preview app and the Chrome app with `cmd+tab`.

But if am reading file2.pdf, `cmd+tab` to Chrome, then `cmd+tab` again, I see file1.pdf (which was opened first) instead of file2.pdf (which I was reading).

Is there a way to `cmd+tab` from Chrome (or any other app of course) back to the last open Preview window?

Comment: Why not just three-finger swipe back again?

Comment: This is a simplified situation; I may have many open windows at the same time, and the 2 windows I need may not me adjacent

Comment: OK. tbh you've found one of the (very many) failings of fullscreen. You'll probably have to resort to the 'hold cmd, then down arrow' method… there's an explanation in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938

Comment: Very weirdly, with my method sometimes I get the desired behaviour and sometimes the wrong one.