# How to access shortcuts for Forward and Backwards in PhpStorm when using a German keyboard on a Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, php

I have recently switched from a PC to a Mac. I'm working a lot in **PhpStorm** and there use the keyboard shortcuts for Forward and Backwards, which on Windows are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>.

Now I read that this is on Mac <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. Fine... but since I use a German keyboard, "]" is on <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> and "[" is on <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> does not navigate me Forward nor Backward.

Is there a meant-to-be solution for this problem? Or am I supposed to actually reconfigure my keyboard to find something that actually works? There must be more people like me having this problem, so I'm curious about what solutions exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for your exact situation, but very often this kind of command stays in the same physical location, even if the letters typed would be different - see [Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275) for a similar situation [that one, however, is compounded by the fact US keyboards are missing the key immediately right of the left shift key, to make it universally true].
I'd definitely try Cmd + the two keys to the right of P, which is where the [ & ] keys are on an English layout.

If you are running Safari, you can check for this visually in the History menu.
This is on a UK English system…

[image]