# Navigate to next tab in finder window using keyboard

Tags: finder, big-sur, navigation

How to navigate to the next already open tab in finder window using keyboard ?

mac osx 11.4

On Ubuntu just do  control + pageup/pagedown

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>  
or backwards
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>

It sits as a 'family' with  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   behaviour for switching apps, & similar to  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  to toggle between windows (see [Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app) )

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd> next tab
- <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd> previous tab

This works in any apps with tabs, including on iPadOS (where ctrl-tab does not).

Comment: I'd forgotten about that one. Was that the old one & they supplemented it at some point with the tab version? It's been so long since I did it by keyboard - these days it's a swipe on my mouse - that I can't remember.