# Why are some Firefox windows not cycling through the entire list of windows I have open?

Tags: firefox

I've got a bunch of open windows in Firefox and somehow two of them (this one included which is the most recent one I've opened) are isolated into their own group. The other 8 or so windows will cycle through when I hit the command-~ key, but this window and the other window in its group never come up and I have to use the mouse and Window menu to select one of those windows. After I select one of the windows in that other group, the command-~ key will cycle through just those two windows and ignores the other 8 windows. Are those different desktop spaces? How can I get all the windows to be in one group?

(I'm talking about browser windows only here. Each window might have any number of tabs in it, but that doesn't seem to be relevant.)

MacOS Sierra, Firefox 89.0 (64-bit)

Comment: This is a side-effect of having windows in separate Spaces, which has never been supported - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938 for some more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move an app window from one space to another

On your Mac, do any of the following:

- Drag the app window you want to move to the edge of the screen. After a moment, the window moves to the next space.
- Go to the space that has the window you want to move, enter Mission Control, then drag the window up to the space you want to use.
- Hold the window's title bar & then use the hot key for the Space you wish to move it to.
- If you drag the window onto a full screen app in the Spaces bar, you can use the apps in Split View.