# How to enable switching between windows of chrome with CMD + ` on Big Sur?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, switching

I read in a lot of questions about this topic that `` cmd + ` ``  should switch the windows, but it simply does not switch the windows, is there some other shortcut in Chrome that prevents this one from working?

Comment: Have you checked with Google's Support to see if that key combo is used within Chrome?

Comment: This is already covered in [Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app)