# Modifying the app switcher keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard

I'm new to macOS.
After more than 20+ years on Windows, I got used to toggling between apps using Alt+tab and also using simple functions as 'copy-paste'.
So, I switched between the 'command' button and the 'control' button and now it is much better. The only thing I couldn't find so far was how to make a specific shortcut for toggling apps on the app switcher that use the same position of the command+tab? (but as I mentioned the command is now the control).

Thanks.

Edit: Thank you very much. I finally downloaded AltTab and it kinda fixed the problem :)

Comment: In 30 years of using both Mac & Windows, I've always considered [modifier] Tab as being one of the most clumsy ways of switching applications. WHy not try something else instead of trying to force key combos on system structures that will fight you forevermore. Try Spaces instead, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme and
https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar

Comment: Please see this answer - https://superuser.com/a/299463

Comment: @sfxedit - that's not what the OP asked. We also have our own Ask Different version of that one - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app

Comment: @Tetsujin I linked to the answer as it explains how to create keyboard shortcuts. I should have clarified that in the comment.

Comment: @sfxedit - you can only change key commands a) if they're already in that list or b) if they exist as a menu item. Cmd/Tab doesn't fit either of those criteria.