# Move focus to next window shortcut not working when having external monitor

Tags: keyboard, display, shortcut, apple-silicon

So I have this weird issue that everytime I connect my **Macbook Air M1** to my **LG Ultrafine 5k** monitor using USB-C, the `Move focus to next window`-shortcut is not working:

[image: Move focus to next keyboard]

It doesn't work if I use my external keyboard, or the integrated keyboard on the Macbook.

If I pull out the USB-C cable the shortcut works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a non-standard key command there, or is your keyboard & input language not English? Default on an English keyboard is ⌘` [backtick] It looks like you changed it, because the command underneath is still English-standard. Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app for more info. There's also the possibility you have 'desktops have different Spaces' This command does not work across different Spaces.

Comment: 'displays have different Spaces' sorry.