# How do you disable Command + Tab (App switcher) in Monterey so that window switcher shortcuts from other applications can replace it?

Tags: shortcut, monterey

I'm trying out Raycast app without any prior experience of its kind such as Alfred. To my astonishment, it has a built-in *Switch Windows* functionality which I can assign a hotkey. I am trying to replace the hotkey for Mac OS' App Switcher with that of Raycast's Window Switcher(CMD+Tab). However, it seems (CMD+Tab) is not an overridable shortcut.

I seriously hate how app switcher works and would love to adopt a more reasonable window switcher without additional applications. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most apps have a switch window facility - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app

Comment: Can't you just use a different shortcut and ignore Cmd-Tab?

Comment: I am used to other hefty commands that utilize Cmd key, so that would be bad.

Comment: Why there is need for ⌘+⇥? Writing `sw` then ⏎ (3 keystrokes) takes you to 'Switch Window' command prompt: `Filter by application name or window title` and from there one can filter any window in any application by text. This ain't anything like macOS built-in graphical window switcher.

Comment: Hi Aivar, I don't understand your comment... Could you explain the steps one more time please?

Comment: You activate Raycast with hotkey you have set. Start writing into prompt: `sw`, it filters out `Switch Window`  (unless you have set `sw` as alias or hotkey) and selects it. Press enter. Now you are in `Switch Window` and its prompt. Filter out any open application or window by entering text for filtering. Select desired, press enter and there you are. Fully keyboard based without need to raise your hands.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to try AltTab (https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app)

But if you made your mind up to use Raycast's Windows Switcher:

- Install Karabiner Elements (https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org)
- Go to config folder (`~/.config/karabiner`)
- Open `karabiner.json`
- Add a rule to "simple_modifications" part

```
            "simple_modifications": [
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "tab",
                        "modifiers": {
                            "mandatory": [
                                "command"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "f13"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

- After saving changes <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> will equivalent to <kbd>F13</kbd>.
- Go to Raycast's preferences and bind <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to Switch Windows

[image: Hotkey on Raycast's Window Switcher]

Comment: Wow I did not know you could have more than one key bind to a custom command. I will definitely try this and savor every moment should it succeed.