# How to switch between windows of same app when on different screens?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I use two screens, one is the laptop's screen and the other one is an external monitor.
I have two windows of Chrome each one on a different screen. If I want to switch between these 2 windows of Chrome, `Cmd ⌘` + `` ` `` is supposed to be working. But it won't work in my case. The focus isn't shifting.
Is there any other keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: This is covered in  [Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app) but you could also use the key command to go directly to the Space you need.

Comment: Ah, I just realised you're talking about two displays, missed that on first read. There's no way to effectively achieve this any faster than just clicking in the correct window. You could so it by key command if you disable 'displays have sepapare Spaces' in Mission Control, but that would change your working paradigm.