# On Mac, I cannot switch between Safari windows using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, safari

I'm losing my mind. I know that Command + ` is *supposed* to allow me to switch between Safari windows on my Mac, but it does nothing. Actually, it does nothing no matter what apps I'm using. Is there a way to set this if it isn't set yet? I went into settings to add it but it's already there. See below.

Note that I'm new to Macs and also a techno-dope. So please, if you can help, speak simply. [image: System Preferences > Keyboard]

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938 - basically it only works if your windows are in the same Space & not fullscreen.

Comment: Also you can always look at the action in the menu bar to determine the actual keyboard shortcut. For example it's possible you configured a custom one for safari in "app shortcuts" (left nav in your screenshot) - the custom one would display in menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Which keyboard layout are you using?
I was having the same issue where <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> wouldn't switch Safari windows. My workaround was <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. After a bit more research the root cause tuned out to be using the US International keyboard layout. Switching to the US layout 'solved' it for me.