# How to achieve direct window switching

Tags: window-manager, application-switcher, switching

I recently got a Mac for work, and one thing is *really* bothering me. For windows and linux there is a concept called "direct window switching," which allows changing windows without regard to which application they are a part of. I typically have dozens of windows and apps open at once, but I'm focused on the 2 most recent image viewers and 2 most recent browser windows. Currently, in mac I have to use a combination of `cmd+tab` and `cmd+`` to switch between these most recent windows. On linux, I had a key combo that would cycle windows of all types, (not applications or windows of an app type). Is there an equivalent somewhere? I can make one using phoenix js if I really need to, but that's a pain.

Comment: You can cycle 'all windows' with Ctrl/F4, but though it theoretically steps back trhough windows in the order they were last selected, in practise it's horribly unreliable & stops when it thinks it's got to the last window. Not recommended. I'd have a look at good Spaces management instead. More reliable. See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193938/85275 for some of the other foibles of single-app window switching.