# How do I use shortcuts with the left square bracket [ key when there is none?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, internationalization

I'm using an M1 MacBook Air with a Swedish keyboard and there is no left square bracket  <kbd>[</kbd>  key though I can do that bracket easily by pressing  <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>  +  <kbd>8</kbd> .

Xcode, however, has several shortcuts containing the   <kbd>[</kbd>  key. Is there any way to use these shortcuts with this keyboard?

Comment: I have a German keyboard which does not have a “[" key either, but I could not find an Xcode shortcut using that key. Can you give an example?

Comment: idk the answer in this particular case, but *sometimes* these commands translate to being in the same position, rather than the same output key. Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275 for a similar situation.

Comment: @MartinR if developing with IntelliJ or similar IDE's developed by JetBrains you can find such shorcuts... e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a non-US English keyboard on my MBP as well. Whenever I come across a keyboard shortcut involving a key that does not exist on that keyboard, I try two things to replace it: the key positioned at the same place on it as the US English keyboard or the key combination on that keyboard that produces the character in the shortcut. Sometimes neither works but frequently one does.

The left square bracket  <kbd>[</kbd>  key on a US English keyboard is located directly to the right of the  <kbd>P</kbd>  key as shown in the picture below. I believe Swedish keyboard has the  <kbd>Å</kbd>  key at the same location as shown in the next picture.

[image: US English Mac Keyboard]

[image: Swedish Mac Keyboard]

Then, for example, for the Xcode indentation shortcut, which is <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>[</kbd> , you could try <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>Å</kbd> . If that doesn't work, then, for the same shortcut, you can try <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> .