# MacBook move focus to recent window instead of next window

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, window-manager

In MacBook, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> cycles through the windows of the same application. However, if I have multiple windows open, then to toggle between two windows, I have to cycle through all the windows. Is there a way to move to the recent window instead of the next window?

The answers to [Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/268997) provide a keyboard shortcut to cycle through the windows of the same application. I know how to cycle through. However, I want to switch to the most recently opened window. For example, say I have five projects open in PyCharm, and I switch from `project1` to `project2`; to come back to `project1`, I don't want to cycle through all the other projects (3,4,5). I want to quickly come back to `project1`.

In Ubuntu, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> achieves. But Mac cycles through all the windows. I want to know how to achieve what Ubuntu does on Mac.

Comment: You can cycle backwards with Cmd+Shift+`. That's slightly better, but not excactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this is that when I'm quickly changing between windows, I need to remember when to hold `Shift` and when not to.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> is what you're looking for?

<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> while holding down the <kbd>command</kbd> key displays all open apps in a graphical "overlay".

Once the overlay is displayed, you can select an app using the arrow keys, or (easier) repeat the <kbd>tab</kbd> key while holding down the <kbd>command</kbd> key. Finally, and I think to address your question, just repeat the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> sequence to alternate back & forth between two apps.

Comment: That's too much work :) I mean, I want to switch between the windows without thinking much and in a fraction of a second. I need this when manually comparing some code across two different projects.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN: I don't understand why you don't see that `cmd-tab` does just that?!

Comment: `cmd`+`tab` switches between different applications. I want to switch between different windows of the same application. Something that `cmd`+`~` does, but it moves around the windows in a cyclic manner. I don't want that. I want to move to the next recently opened window (exactly like `cmd`+`tab`) but within the same application. Hope that clarifies