# How to stop automatic switching of Space when switching between apps?

Tags: mojave, mission-control

When I have the same app opened on more than 1 Space, switching between apps sometimes brings me to another Space. This is very disorientating.

A specific example is: I have a few Chrome windows opened in Space 1 and a few more opened in Space 2. When I switch to Chrome using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, sometimes the Space switching takes place too.

How can I make switching apps (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and switching between windows of the same app (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>) stay in the same Space?

I have made the configuration below, So <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> stays within the same Space. But <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> still triggers Space switching if I have the Same app opened in more than 1 space.

System Preferences → Mission Control

1. Disable *When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application*.
2. Disable *Group windows by application*.

Comment: I think your problems starts right at the first sentence. Spaces was never designed to handle apps spread to more than one Space. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50445/switching-between-windows-of-one-application-in-multiple-spaces?rq=1 for some workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  

For my desktop setup,  I run Chrome with my personal profile in one Space (together with other personal apps) and Chrome with work profile in another.  This is to keep personal and work stuffs in different Spaces.  

Unfortunately, switching from other apps to Chrome sometimes trigger space switching.  This is quite annoying.